Using Google Sheets to calculate electricity bill with Different Tariff

This is the table that I use to calculate electricity bill, all I need is just edit the cell which highlighted in yellow (Usage per month). If the usage is above 600, the calculation is correct, but when the usage is less than 600, then something is wrong.

The cell which has a value of -100 should be zero.
This is my formula for the column.





Any idea how to solve this?
I tried MIN;MAX. but error.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

SUGGESTION
You can try this formula:
=map(B5:B8, array_constrain(scan(C11, B4:B8, lambda(a,c,a-sum(c))), rows(B5:B8), 1), lambda(x, y, if(min(y,x)>0, min(y,x), 0)))

Kindly clear all the values on cells C5:C8, and paste this formula on cell C5 only.
OUTPUT


You're welcome! Glad to know it works well for you.
